# Using Bayes Theorem?

Tags: probability

> A certain town has two taxi companies, the Green Taxi Co (cars coloured green) and the Blue
>   Taxi Co (cars coloured blue). 10% of taxis are the Green and 90% are the Blue. There was an
>   accident on a dark evening, and the witness claimed a Green cab was involved. On future testing, they discovered that under the conditions of that evening, there was an 80% chance of correct identification of the cab colour (regardless of colour) and 20% chance of erring in colour identification. (assume neither company is more accident prone than the other)
>
> a. Before actually hearing the testimony of this witness, what is the probability that the
>   witness will claim that it was a Blue Cab involved in the accident that night?
>
> b. If we now have the testimony of the witness, who declares that the cab was Green, what
>   is the probability that it actually was Green?

I used a probability tree to solve this question but apparently, it was actually related to Bayes theorem. How I did (a) was use the probability tree and got $P(Witness~claims~Blue) = (0.9)(0.8)+(0.1)(0.2)=0.74$.
For (b), $P(Actually~green) = (0.1)(0.8)+(0.1)(0.2)=0.10$.

However, the answer for (b) was $\frac{.08}{.26}$ and I was supposed to use the Bayes Theorem. Can someone please explain why the Bayes is to be used instead of a sum of probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $100 $ accidents happened which involves $90$  blue and $10$ green cars.The witness

will claim $26$ green which consists of $8$ actual green and $18$ blues.So , if we already

know that witness claimed green, only $8/26$ will be from actual green cars.